# Separate radio buttons elements in RadioGroupItem with smart GWT

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, smartgwt

I'm new to GWT and I want to separate the radio elements in a RadioGroupItem. My RadioGroupItem contains two individual radio values. For instance

*Radio A

*Radio B

And what I want to do is to separate them and also be able to put more widgets or components in the separation between those two radio values. For example:

*Radio A

(DataGrid)

(ComboBoxItem)

*Radio B

(DataGrid)

(TextFieldItem)

Is there some way to achieve this distribution with the RadioGroup?

```
RadioGroupItem groupRc1 = new RadioGroupItem();
        groupRc1.setTitle("");
        groupRc1.setValueMap("Radio A", "Radio B");
        groupRc1.setDefaultValue("Radio A");
```

I think it should be a way to do it as with a GUI Java SE application in which you create a ButtonGroup and add the RadioButton1 and RadioButton2 to that button group.

I tried with .setAttribute("cellPadding", 70); and I get the space but I can't put any component in the separation. Please, I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `current behavior` is by design. The spacing between items is calculated `automatically` based on the `RadioGroup's` size and the maximum number of the items that is displayed in the column.

As you tried we can achieve padding but unable to insert`elements` `inbetween`

If you want an custom behavior:

- You need to write your own `widget class`

or

- You
  need to create individual radio buttons and setting false the other radio buttons in `ClickHandlers`(Which is quite common thing).

Comment: thank you very much, I implemented my own widget, kind of tricky when working with the single radios, but at could do it at the end. Thanks! :)